# Vuejs redirect on enter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How can I redirect when anyone try to enter in my app if he are not logged?

I'm using this code in my App.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  created() {
    this.$router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      if (this.$store.getters.isLogado) {
        next();
      } else {
        console.log('Stop');
        debugger;
      }
    });
  },
};
```

But if my user type in http://myapp/users the app enter on /users and then if he try to navigate the vue enter on beforeEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to show you how i use authentication guard in my application.

**auth.js**

```
import { store } from "../../store/store";

export default function (Vue) {
  Vue.auth = {
    isAuthenticated () {
      return store.getters.isLogged
    },
  }

  Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $auth: {
      get () {
        return Vue.auth
      }
    }
  })

}
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { store } from '../store/store'
import Auth from './services/Auth'

Vue.use(Auth)

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name === 'Login') { //if user goes to login page
    if (Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) { //if is authenticated
      next({name: 'notFound'})
    }else {
      next()
    }
  }else if (to.name === 'notFound') { //if user tries to go to notFound
      next()
  }else { //if user tries any other url
    if (Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      next()
    } else {
      next({name: 'notFound'})
    }
  }

})


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

That is a good practice to follow.If you don't understand it and it does not help you,then to answer your question regarding your code you posted look below:

```
import store from './store'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
    if (store.getters.isLogado) {
      next()
    }else {
      next({name: 'YouRouteName_you_want_to_navigate'})
    }
  },
};
```

Or:

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  created() {
   if(this.$store.getters.isLogado){
      next()
   }else{
    this.$router.push('ThePathYouWant')
   }
  }
};
```